# Regarding returning of private member while using scope resolution

Tags: c++

I have been taught that `scope resolution` does nothing but gives user the functionality to just `declare function inside the class` and give the corresponding `definition outside of the class`. In my case I want to `return private member` but when I use `scope resolution` then I get `error` but when I `don't use scope resolution` and have the `definition inside the class` and `return the same private member` I `don't get any error`. Can some one please explain me why? Till now my understanding was that behavior and everything remains same while using scope resolution and the only difference is we use scope resolution just to define function outside. I never knew that if I need to return a private member then I cannot use scope resolution I am bound to define the function inside the class only. Can some one please throw some light on it. Thanks ! Is my understanding correct?

Below is the code snippet:

```
class Bst
{
private:
    int maxnum,minnum;
    struct node
    {
        node *left;
        int data;
        node *right;
    }*root;
public:
node * min ();
};
node * Bst::min ()
//^^^ error at this place
    {

//some code
}
```

Same code without scope resolution

```
class Bst
{
private:
    int maxnum, minnum;
    struct node
    {
        node *left;
        int data;
        node *right;
    }*root;
public:
    node * min() //  No error      
    {
        //some code
    }
};
```

Comment: Post your actual code (if there's a lot of it, reduce it to the minimum that illustrates your problem) with compiler error(s).

Comment: You have been taught wrongly, `::` has many uses.

Comment: Posting the code to shows the problem would go a long way in getting some positive feedback.

Comment: Bst::node * Bst::min ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define your method outside the class, it needs to look like this:

```
Bst::node * Bst::min ()
```